# Delete till end of current parenthesis block in vim

Tags: linux, vim, text-editor

Say I am editing this json

```
{
  "a": {"language": "python"},
  "b": {},
  "c": {"language": "java"},
  "d": {"encoding": "utf-16"}
}
```

My cursor is at `b` of `"b": {}`. I want to delete till the end of current  `{}` block. So it'll look like,

```
{
  "a": {"language": "python"},
  "
}
```

Looks little odd. But explains what I want.

How can I do that in Vim?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `d]}`.
From `:help ]}`:

```
                                    *]}*
]}          go to [count] next unmatched '}'.
            |exclusive| motion.
```

The help also says that this is one of the motion's use case:

```
The above four commands can be used to go to the start or end of the current
code block.  It is like doing "%" on the '(', ')', '{' or '}' at the other
end of the code block, but you can do this from anywhere in the code block.
```

Comment: Hey @Marth, what if I had `[1, 2, |3, 4, 5]` (where | is the cursor position), and I wanted to delete till the last `]`, so that I end up with `[1, 2, |]` as of now doing `d]]` deletes the till the end of the file which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

for your example, `d]]` works too. It is easier to press. 
However, `]}` is better, since it works no matter which column the `{ or }` sits on.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```
V f ^ } k k d
```